# Dropdown buttons for figures with multiple lines per plot/trace

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a dropdown button in plotly that would allow for plotting multiple vectors at once for a subset of data (or, to have multiple traces for the same dropdown button). These subsets would be chosen via the above-mentioned button.

Here's a toy example in `plotly.express`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        x=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
        y1=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
        y2=[2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0],
        z=["a", "a", "b", "b"],
    )
)
px.scatter(df, x="x", y=["y1", "y2"], symbol="z")
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is a dropdown button that would select a subset for distinct z values ("a" or "b").

Unfortunately, `go.Scatter` does not seem like to have multiple `y` arrays and I end up with a complete mess.

```py
zs = df.z.unique()
dropdown_buttons = []
fig = go.Figure()

for i, val in enumerate(zs):
    df_ = df.query(f'z=="{val}"')
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df_["x"],
            y=df_[["y1", "y2"]],
            name=val,
        )
    )
    dropdown_buttons.append(
        {
            "label": val,
            "method": "update",
            "args": [
                {"visible": [x == i for x in range(len(zs))]},
                {"title": val},
            ],
        }
    )

fig.update_layout(
    {
        "updatemenus": [
            {
                "type": "dropdown",
                "showactive": True,
                "active": 0,
                "buttons": dropdown_buttons,
            }
        ]
    }
)
fig.show()
```

[image]